# Python Thread counter

Tags: python, multithreading, counter

I'm trying to make thread counter but I'm stuck. I've got the code below:

```
import threading

def Hello():
    global t
    print("Hello!")
    t = threading.Timer(1, Hello)
    t.start()

Hello()
```

How can I make the loop stop say after 5 'Hellos'?

Comment: What does "I'm stuck" mean? Please, as a new user here, start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, in particular for Python, proper formatting is important! You can [edit] your question to fix the formatting and perhaps include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish but this code will work

```
import threading

count = 0
def hello():
    global count
    print("Hello!")
    count += 1
    if count < 5:
        t = threading.Timer(1, function=hello,)
        t.start()

hello()
```